# Git 3-way merge of a file with uncommitted changes, it's original version and another file

Tags: git

There is the command `git merge-file` which accepts 3 files and does a 3-way merge on them. Is there some short-hand command that 3-way merges a file with uncommitted changes, it's last committed version and another file? What about the same question but for all files within a directory?